# Verbose AspectJ compiler output

Tags: ide, intellij-idea, aspectj

I wonder if there any way to make compiler's output in IntelliJ IDEA more verbose. IDEA automatically sets up compiler to `ajc` from maven dependencies.

[image: screenshot of the compiler output in IntelliJ]

I assume that it can be not IntelliJ IDEA's problem. May be `ajc` needs additional arguments ?

Thanks.

Comment: _IDEA automatically sets up compiler to ajc from maven dependencies._ we have the same issue. Definitely it's an Idea bug(10.5.2 we use): even after you manually change java compiler to javac - idea returns it to acj

Comment: @yetanothercoderu actually, we see this as a feature. If you don't need ajc to build your project you better remove it from Maven as well.

Comment: @RomanShevchenko May be it should be managable feature? :) Also if it's feature then compiler also have to take compiler parameters from maven, but it's don't.
My situation: maven build works well, but Ajc falls with exception in temp file somewhere in AppData... for me it's faster to switch to javac

Comment: I also think, that it should be a managable feature. Currently I resolved an issue by deactivating AspectJ plugin.

Comment: @yetanothercoderu it's manageable - you can disable automatic Maven importing. Disabling the plugin also works well - looks like you just don't need it's functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This message is rather from IDEA itself, not from Ajc.

AspectJ support in IDEA is still work-in-progress so it's better to use latest IDEA version (10.5 at the moment).

Please make sure that compiler is properly set up (File | Settings | Compiler | Java Compiler). Use "Test" button there.

Check IDEA logs for any related messages or exceptions.

If still no progress please file an issue to [JetBrains tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/).

Comment: Yeah. When error occurs IDEA write ajc error log in some temp file in appdata. It should be improved for sure.

Comment: @konoplianko it's ajc, not IDEA. In IDEA 11 it will be started from project directory so these "core dumps" will be easier to find.

Comment: I've reviewed this issue one more time. There is trouble that for example Ajc using only by one maven module (but we have lots of them). But compiler in intelliJ can be setup only for whole project, and intelliJ autoimports ajc for the whole project but not javac.

Comment: That's true. Do you have any objections with using Ajc for entire project?

Answer (score 1):

Still having this issue with 2019.1.
I found the log with the full exception in "~/.IntelliJIdea2019.1/system/log/build-log/build.log"